# Union members exclusively in a class depending on different types

Tags: c++, class, unions

I am implementing a class where each instantiation has a handle which will be exclusively dependent on a member `type`. Different types are associated with different handles.

```
enum class Type {
  TypeA, TypeB, TypeC;
};

class HandleA { ... };
class HandleB { ... };
class HandleC { ... };

class Foo {
  public:
    Type type;
    std::unique_ptr<HandleA> handleA;
    std::unique_ptr<HandleB> handleB;
    std::unique_ptr<HandleC> handleC;
};
```

Ideally, `handleA` exists if the type is `TypeA`, `handleB` exists if the type is `TypeB`, and `handleC` exists if the type is `TypeC`. However, I believe there should be a better design pattern for this. Otherwise, the more types I have, the more `unique_ptr` will be occupied in the class `Foo`. I know `union` might be a good solution here but I am wondering whether there exists `c++` or `c++11` solutions that can be more scalable. Since Foo might be used in a virtual manner for other derived classes which will take different constructors, I am not looking for a templated solution.

Comment: simple: make `Foo` a class template

Comment: Union looks like it's tailored for this, if only ever one handle per Foo had to exist. Alternatively, put your pointer into a `std::any`? RTTI handling causes overhead though, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Have a look at `boost::variant`

Comment: you always have the option of hiding everything behind a `void*` and keep track with `type`. very flexible but easier to mess up.

Comment: Is `type` a compile-time constant? If not, can it change during a Foo's lifetime? If so, what happens to the Handle?

Comment: Can you have each of the Handle classes derive from a common base type which defines the interface that all of them implement? That would be a much more "C++" solution.

Comment: I was wondering... even though a template Foo is not acceptable, mayhap a `template<Type T> class Handle` is?

Comment: @Zsar Yes. The type could be a compile time constant.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with the requirements a bit and find that the fundamental problem to solve here is: How does one choose a type at runtime.

Everything else can be solved with a bit of template magic - which fails where Foo itself shall not be a template.

Any trickery to overcome this issue, then, (we could do some amazing things with member-function pointers) seems to affort us nothing but to reimplement the VTable indirection virtual functions already give us for free. Under this consideration, I am inclined to follow the comment of @RobK :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

enum class Type { TypeA, TypeB, TypeC };

class Handle
{
public:
  // virtual ~Handle() = default; // if any subclass is not empty
  virtual std::string sing() const = 0; // purely virtual function
};
class HandleA : public Handle { public: std::string sing() const { return "Aaha"; } };
class HandleB : public Handle { public: std::string sing() const { return "Behe"; } };
class HandleC : public Handle { public: std::string sing() const { return "Cehe"; } };

class Foo
{
  Type type;
  std::unique_ptr<Handle> handle;

public:
  constexpr Foo(Type newType) : type{newType}, handle()
  {
    switch(newType) // establishes the mapping between Type and Handle-subclass
    {
      case Type::TypeA: this->handle.reset(new HandleA()); return;
      case Type::TypeB: this->handle.reset(new HandleB()); return;
      case Type::TypeC: this->handle.reset(new HandleC()); return;
    }
  }

  // virtual function call automatically resolves to used subclass
  void showHandle() const { std::cout << this->handle->sing() << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Foo fooA(Type::TypeA);
  Foo fooB(Type::TypeB);
  Foo fooC(Type::TypeC);

  fooA.showHandle();
  fooB.showHandle();
  fooC.showHandle();
}
```

Note that there are a few things to keep in mind when using incomplete types such as my Handle in this way:

1. If any subclass defines its own non-static member objects, Handle and *all* subclasses have to receive a declared virtual destructor.

   - Without, the destruction of objects of such a subclass is incomplete and will leak memory.
   - Like the commented-out destructor in Handle, those can just be defaulted.
2. Not overriding a purely virtual function such as my Handle::sing and then calling it will immediately terminate the program.